# Marking question as duplicate of duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

While in the Low-Quality and Close queues, I often come across questions marked as duplicates by a previous user. However, the proposed original is often *itself* marked as a duplicate of another question or closed for another reason. Is it my job as a dutiful reviewer to mark the post in question as a duplicate of the "original" copy of the question, or can I just mark it as a duplicate-of-a-duplicate and move on with my life?

To rephrase the question, is the point of closing a question as a duplicate to point the OP to the canonical question (which hopefully has some decent answers), or is it simply to deactivate the question for maintenance purposes?

Examples:

1. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425825/can-the-scanner-class-be-used-to-read-the-names-of-all-of-the-txt-files-in-a-sp) was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384947/java-find-txt-files-in-specified-folder).
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527976/java-inheritance-accessing-super-class-variables-inside-subclass) was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584377/java-how-to-call-method-of-grand-parents).

Comment: If I see that sort of thing, I try and link to the canonical question behind all those duplicate links.

Comment: I’ve seen that a lot, too.  What I do is trace back and find the root posting and use that instead. Yes, it’s more work but it is also more helpful.  It is also much less likely to have been already closed.

Comment: Perhaps the software could help by calling attention to the duplicate status and automatically adding the base question to the menu.

Comment: So, if a question is marked as a duplicate of another one and the other one is marked as not a real question...  is it really a duplicate or just not a real question?  (Example 1)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Authoritative guidance to consider in cases like this is the definition in [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) at MSE:

> we want to tell the user ...something like, *“Somebody already asked this. If that other question doesn't solve your problem, please clarify your question to explain how it's different.”* Perfect: if the other question helps them, they're **happy because they got an answer**. If the other question doesn't help them, they know exactly what to do. No argument about how exact an "exact duplicate" needs to be...

The point is to refer question readers to where it is answered. Now, if you think of it, question `A` having an answer in `B` does not automatically guarantee that it also has an answer in `C`, even though question `B` may have its answer in `C`.

For a simplified example, imagine "chain of duplicates" like as follows:

- `Question A:` How do I see result of multiplying 2 by 2?

  - `Question B:` How do I multiply?
    `answer:`
    You invoke `multiply` method of `arith` package. In order to view result, you invoke method of `display` package.

    - `Question C:` How do I do arithmetic operations?
      `answer:`
      You invoke appropriate method of `arith` package, like `multiply`, `divide` etc.

It's easy to imagine readers being satisfied by closures `A -> B` and `B -> C` since answers given solve the problems asked about.

However, closure `A -> C` would be problematic: first question asks about how to display results, while answer in the second question says nothing about this.

<sup>Note how question in `B` does not ask about displaying results, making dupe closure look reasonable. Also note how answer in `B` provides guidance *beyond* its scope, along with addressing the question asked.</sup>

---

For a more realistic example, refer to the "non-transitive" chain of duplicates at Meta Stack Exchange:

- `Question A':` [Spiteful downvoting? Two fast DVs to my unrelated posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178703/165773)

  - `Question B':` [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28756/165773)

    - `Question C':` [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/165773)

`A'` is closed as a duplicate of `B'`, which is in turn closed as a duplicate of `C'`.

If you take a closer look at [revisions history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/178703/revisions) and [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178703/spiteful-downvoting-two-fast-dvs-to-my-unrelated-posts#comment539909_178703), you will notice that initial closure has been changed from `A' -> C'` to *narrower* one, `A' -> B'` because readers disagreed that *widest* dupe target has answers relevant to the question asked in `A'`.

Answer (score 9):

My view on this (and not necessarily agreed on by everybody else) is that you should vote to close as duplicate of that question that is most similar to the one you are closing.

Duplicates are rarely exactly the same. Some questions closed as duplicate today are disputed and re-opened tomorrow. If A is closed as duplicate of B, and B is already marked as duplicate of C, then if the B-C relation is disputed and B is re-opened, then A may still be a bona-fide duplicate of B, but if it had been closed as duplicate of C on the grounds that C is the "root duplicate", then the A-C relation would also have to be reconsidered.

I realize that may approach can lead to long chains of duplicate relations. It should be the job of search engines (the Stackoverflow one as well as Google and others) to show these chains/clusters of duplicates to users in a way that makes it easy to find the root duplicate, as well as the various answers given on the various duplicates. Search engines may not do this in the best possible way right now, but they should.

Answer (score 3):

9 years later, I wish to offer a dissenting perspective with the benefit of hindsight.

Chains of duplicate markings are bad, and this is clearer now as a result of changes to closure reasons since 2014 as well as other general shifts in how policy is understood and applied.

After all this time, there hasn't been particularly good support - either in the site software, or in external search - for dealing with these chains. I understand that logged-out users will be automatically referred along a duplicate link, but I don't know if this applies transitively. Even then, there certainly isn't any support for viewing the entire chain in an elegant way. In which case, why bother to record the links in the chain?

Identifying canonicals is important; we want to centralize information in order to build the best possible reference library. If people are commonly using a dupe to close other questions as dupes, *there is a problem that needs to be investigated*:

- Was the closure at the "top" of the chain actually merited? Maybe there is a subtle distinction that instead calls for those two questions to reference each other in a different way.
- Maybe the question being used really is just better (in spite of prior age/votes/view count/whatever), and should become the new canonical.
- Maybe a lot of people just have one specific question saved (per the site feature; or "bookmarked" as they think of it because they did it years ago and that's what the feature was called; or bookmarked using a local browser feature; etc.) and there should be some kind of promotion/advertisement of the fact that a better canonical has been found.

There are almost certainly other possibilities that slip my mind at the moment.

Redirecting links directly to a canonical is one of the most powerful tools current-day curators have, to highlight that this is where the high-quality (and up-to-date, if applicable) information now resides in spite of the inertia of old votes.

---

Reproducing the "see result of multiplying 2 by 2" example for discussion:

- `Question A:` How do I see result of multiplying 2 by 2?

  - `Question B:` How do I multiply?
    `answer:`
    You invoke `multiply` method of `arith` package. In order to view result, you invoke method of `display` package.

    - `Question C:` How do I do arithmetic operations?
      `answer:`
      You invoke appropriate method of `arith` package, like `multiply`, `divide` etc.

Question B was in some sense wrong to offer out-of-scope guidance - unless there's a reason to expect that guidance to be necessary for a large fraction of people who have the question. In any event, question C is almost certainly better suited as a canonical. Other arithmetic operations (in this hypothetical language that requires third-party library support for operators!) presumably work the same way, and there's no good reason to give customized advice for each in separate places.

So, if displaying the result is something that commonly needs explanation, question C should offer a *related* link to the canonical for displaying things. Question A arguably *needs more focus*, since it is unwittingly asking about two things. However:

- Since question C exists, and there is presumably also a canonical around about displaying results, the question can simply be duped with both links.
- On the other hand, if the two questions are *commonly* asked together (especially if it's in one breath, without a conjunction, as in the example here) then that combination *may merit* its own "stub" canonical. The "multiplication" part of the question should still be broadened to cover other arithmetic operators. The initial answer should be short:

  ```
  [Use the `arith` package to compute a result](question C) and then [display it with the `display` package](question D). For example:

      <fully worked code example>
  ```

  The linked canonicals would still be the place for any package-specific information about installation (which might in turn link to a canonical about how to install FooLang packages), details about advanced usage of the corresponding packages, etc.

  Creating a stub like this admits the possibility of other answers - in case another way exists (or emerges) to solve the two problems together (maybe a `showcomputed` package becomes popular later).

Duping with a non-canonical, simply because it happens to be more specific to the OP's exact phrasing / additional requirements / etc., is just not how the site is intended to work. It comes from the same mindset as people disputing duplicate closures because of irrelevant differences.

As for Meta, I don't really care about duplicate links on the Meta sites, since **the site software is not particularly amenable to meta discussion anyway**. There's not the same motivation to fix canonical links on meta because a) there are relatively few Q&As on Meta that actually need to be treated as "authoritative"; b) the ones that are, are consciously created as part of a "FAQ".