# Requesting flagging guidelines - not an answer scenario

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, link-only-answers

When I was going through the new questions, I came across this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062781/linux-system-monitoring/28062832#28062832 . Well, the question in itself was off-topic because the OP had asked for a system monitoring tool. So, I flagged it accordingly and that flag got reviewed as helpful.

But then I saw there was an answer to that question, containing just a link to a tool. Now, from the rules of SO I comprehend, link only answers are to be treated as "not an answer" so I flagged that also. I would also like to say that the link originally posted was itself flawed as a `,` got in (possible typo). But my flag got declined with a reason -  **declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it**.

I really do respect the SO community and the mods; how they help make a good environment for greenhorns like myself. But I really want to understand the reason behind this decline. So that from next time on I can be even more careful as to which things should be flagged or not flagged.

Furthermore I also have another doubt, if a question has been flagged and put on hold, is it necessary to flag answers which are really not up to the mark or per SO rules?

I know the meta is full of questions like "why my flag got declined" but if answered, it would really help my understanding about detailed moderation guidelines.

**EDIT**

Well it might seem my question is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate and maybe closed also very soon, but my doubt / dilemma will not disappear unfortunately. Plus most people will think it is TL;DR.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/1110381 and the other related links here. TL;DR "not an answer" flags are only for cases where it's extremely clear that the content of the post is definitely not an answer to any possible question.

Comment: well the -- "Mods do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags. If your flag requires a mod to evaluate an answer from the question's perspective, do not use a "Not an Answer" flag on it."  explains it all..

Comment: If you leave out the link the answer is still somewhat useful. If it would have said *see this awesome tool, check it out* the answer is useless without the link.

Comment: I agree to you @rene, but I guess the guidelines of SO regarding link only answers has been fairly clear. It might seem I am ranting over one declined flag, but the real reason is, I want to know if the rules are strictly enforced or are flexible based on certain situations and if they are flexible then what are the considerations.

Comment: @rene disagree; by that logic saying "check out Windows Media Player, it's a really good tool!" would be a "somewhat useful" answer as well. Just dropping a name does not add anything of value (and btw the name can easily be extracted out of the link, so your example would, by your standards, not be less useful). The core problem here is of course that the question is bad and inherently off-topic, but I believe that even on softwarerecommendations.SE there's a requirement to qualify an answer and not just drop a name and link, so people can evaluate the features without visiting the link.

Comment: @l4mpi Oh, maybe I should have pointed out that I think both answers are crap and will get my downvote if I run into those. I only try to make clear why flagging as NAA fails in some cases. I agree with your position on the question. Feel free to seek help in closing that type of questions in the [SO Close Voters room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: @l4mpi exactly my point, but in some cases I am seeing link only answers are getting endorsed, so the flagging as NAA boil downs to human judgment and perception right ???

Comment: now the answer itself is deleted and not shown on the question.. I guess moderators made a discussion and decided to delete it ??? or the OP of the answer deleted it ???

Comment: @RicoRicochet deleted by owner

Comment: that question in itself is a duplicate.. so my question is duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate..

Comment: what i ultimately feel is no matter how much we try to define moderation activities, "It WILL ALWAYS come down to the individual judgment / gut feelings / little angels and devils on our shoulders".. Like my comment or not, but I think after looking deeply in meta-posts I can conclude that this "link only - NAA situation - flag decline" is not new and it will keep on happenning..

Comment: duplicate closure is [not necessarily transitive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268485/839601). As for moderators acting inconsistently, about dozen meta questions about [declined flags on link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/link-only-answers+declined-flags) suggest that this is indeed so