# Why are my best answers not the ones that get the most upvotes

Tags: discussion, voting

The answers that I have given on the site to date that I feel either I put the most time and thought into, or that were quick but insightful, are generally not the ones that get the most up-votes. I don't think there's a large difference in the number of views, they are all somewhere around 100-200 views.

Why is this?

My theory right now is that, the only answers that attract a lot of upvotes are the kind of answers that someone can skim very quickly and be 90% sure that it's the right answer.

A different theory is that I'm simply wrong about which answers that I've given are valuable to people, and that's the criteria that people use when upvoting.

This is just a discussion question, I'm not really proposing any change or anything, it's more just "am I right?"

Comment: Your theory is largely correct. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate of an already-duplicate question? :)

Comment: @Rob: Actually I noticed that that is a trend on stack overflow... it's pretty common to have chains of duplicates. Maybe there should be a triage queue / a badge for correcting duplicates of duplicates so that they point to the single best parent question... :shrug:

Comment: This is also known as ["bikeshedding"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange).

Comment: @ChrisBeck see [Marking question as duplicate of duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250202/839601) (duplicates are often non transitive, and having single canonical dupe target is not always possible / practical)