# Marking really old and popular questions/answers as duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question/answer: [Run a JAR file from the command line and specify classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-jar-from-command-line-and-specify-classpath)

Was asked over 3 years ago, and is exceedingly popular (in both views and upvotes) for both the question and the answer.

Earlier today, someone marked this question as a duplicate of another, far less popular and informative question. [Execute jar file with multiple classpath libraries from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018100/execute-jar-file-with-multiple-classpath-libraries-from-command-prompt)

This other question is overly confusing, bogged down by irrelevant information, and the answer isn't even a real answer to the problem (the correct answer isn't the accepted answer). Essentially this other question and answer are of exceedingly poor quality.

Was this an appropriate use of "duplicate question"?

Comment: Someone's already gone and reopened the question, so the likely and direct answer is "no, this wasn't a good dupe target."

Comment: @Makoto how do we remove the "this question is a duplicate of" header?

Comment: @Makoto Actually, it's never even been closed.

Comment: @Kendra:  [It had been.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18413014/timeline)  I'm just not seeing where it was reopened.  I blame my contacts.

Comment: @SnakeDoc You're the _only one_ who sees that header. It just means someone has proposed a duplicate for your question to be closed as. It has not yet been closed, and will need 5 close votes in order to get there.

Comment: @Makoto [Not according to the revisions.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18413014/revisions) Clicking on the "close" link in the timeline takes you to the review item for it- Looks like that just tells you a review item was made for the post, in the close queue. Edit: Upon refresh, that item on the timeline is gone. Might only be available if the item is _in_ a queue at the moment. Might also be something we're not actually supposed to see.

Comment: I *swear* I saw a close notice there.

Comment: @Makoto I did too in the revision link you provided.

Comment: I saw the close notice on the timeline, but clicking it [took you here.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11298940) It was voted "Leave Open" so it looks like completing the review removed the item. A bit odd.

Comment: @Kendra that makes sense. Timing was a bit odd there. So I guess the answer to this question here is, "no, it's not a good duplicate candidate".

Comment: The "far less popular" question has (currently) the same number of votes, and more views. I agree the answer on your question seems better.

Comment: [duplicate is not always transitive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268485/839601)

Comment: Just a note, @Makoto and SnakeDoc, I asked a question on MSE about the timeline issue. You can find it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items) if you're interested.