# Duplicate points to other duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This seems like a question that should already exist, but I haven't been able to find it (I have searched)

What should we do on finding a marked duplicate with the linked original also marked as a duplicate?

ie. A is marked as a duplicate of B, but B is marked as a duplicate of C.  In this case shouldn't the link be updated from `A -> B -> C` to `A -> C`?

The example I found is:

[A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903625/passing-variables-through-a-promise-chain) ->
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises) ->
[C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Comment: this relation is [generally non-transitive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268485/839601)

Comment: Oh, the irony. At least the duplicate doesn't point to another duplicate (at the time of writing).

Comment: Anyone even tried to have a circle situation with duplicates? Like A -> B -> C -> A. That would be lovely for a question like this one :P

Answer (score 6):

I guess in many of those cases, A is closed as a duplicate of B before B is closed as a duplicate of C. There's no need to update the links because the questions (except for A) cannot be deleted, so the reader will always be able to arrive at C.
If we wanted users to immediately arrive at C (which happens [under certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr)), I imagine it would be automated by the system instead of making users update the duplicate links.

Also, in some cases A is an exact duplicate of B (same question and answer) while B is a non-exact duplicate of C (similar question, same answer applies). In such case, it's preferred to close A as a duplicate of B, not of C.