# How are duplicate chains resolved?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The question [What is the difference between normal rvalue reference and template rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707172/what-is-the-difference-between-normal-rvalue-reference-and-template-rvalue-refer) is closed as a duplicate, but the linked duplicate ([What is the rationale behind forwarding references and rvalue references sharing the same syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302849/what-is-the-rationale-behind-forwarding-references-and-rvalue-references-sharing)) is itself closed as a duplicate of [Why do forwarding references have the same syntax as rvalue references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364297/why-do-forwarding-references-have-the-same-syntax-as-rvalue-references).

The "middle" duplicate is an identical question to the one that isn't closed as a duplicate.    How are these situations handled?  Shouldn't there be a "canonical" non-closed question that all the duplicates point to?

I was going to mod-flag the first question, but decided to ask here instead.

*It will be hilarious if this meta-question is closed as a duplicate, but also very frustrating.  I search **a lot** before asking questions but SO search almost never recommends viable options.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should duplicate questions be linked to the original question or any duplicate question in the chain?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381784/should-duplicate-questions-be-linked-to-the-original-question-or-any-duplicate-q) it doesn't seem to really have a community consensus, but it's one user who closes in this way explaining why they do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your specific concern is with duplicate chains. A researcher can easily click through to the top level duplicate if they want, they also can benefit from all of the answers in the entire chain if they find they need more or different information than is contained in the canonical.

Comment: @HenryEcker IMO duplicate chains just sow confusion about the "right" answer.  Plus there's the analogy with the endless phone menu.

Comment: there are many different ways one may ask the same question, and depending on which way it is asked, and with what context, one dupe target may be better than another.

Comment: @KevinB That's as may be, but in this case they are really identical

Comment: it's possible one was just easier to find than the other? the dupe search is notoriously bad. anyone with a relevant gold tag badge can fix it, just leave a comment for the future gold badger

Comment: @KevinB Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Shouldn't the meta-canonical be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250202 ?